# Trying to change a label using a static method

Tags: c#, label, static-methods

I have two forms Form1 which has the class `CharStats` inside it and Mainform which has the class `MainForm`. `MainForm` has a label associated with it `pcNameLabel` and `CharStats` contains a button which is supposed to change the `pcNameLabel.Text` when it is clicked. Since I'm communicating between forms and classes I have a static method `SetInfo()` setup inside `MainForm` which is called by a method `StatTransfer()` inside of `CharStats`. The whole thing almost works right except that I can't modify `pcNameLabel.Text` from inside the static method `SetInfo()` because of the static non static thing. So how do I do this.

Mainform (I cut out some non relevant data that handles variables)

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        int statHolder;
        int statAdjuster;
        string healthHolder;
        int finalHealth;
        int diceOut;
        int maxDice;
        int healingOnOff = 0;
        int pcOrEn = 0;
        int turnCount = 0;
        int diceType;
        int diceResult;
        public static int formInit = 0;
        public static string VariableLabel1;
        public static string Variable2;

        Random _r = new Random();


        public MainForm()
        {

            CharStats form = new CharStats();
            form.Show();

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static void SetInfo()
        {
            Variable2 = VariableLabel1;
            pcNameLabel.Text = Variable2;   
        }
    }
```

Form1 (Also cut out variable handling data)

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
    {
        string name = "";
        string health = "";
        string mana = "";
        string strength = "";
        string agility = "";
        string intelligence = "";


        public CharStats()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void Fighter()
        {
        name = "Reginaldxxxxxxx";
        health = "200";
        mana = "50";
        strength = "16";
        agility = "12";
        intelligence = "6";
        }

        public void StatTransfer()
        {
            MainForm.VariableLabel1 = Name;
            MainForm.formInit = 1;
            MainForm.SetInfo();
        }

        void FighterButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Fighter();
            StatTransfer();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well which *instance* of the form do you want to change the text on? It's not at all clear to me that `SetInfo` should be static in the first place.

Comment: When its not static I can't access it from form1. The text is in mainform

Comment: Well you'd need to call it on *an instance* of `MainForm`. That's the point. Form1 (which is apparently actually called `CharStats`) should have an instance of `MainForm` in order to manipulate that instance. Imagine there were two `MainForm` instances shown at the same time - how would anything know which form to change?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with instances, but I do understand what your saying. If I understand right I need to change things a fair bit. Instead of calling an instance of `MainForm` in Form1(the form is called form 1 and it has a class in it called `CharStats`), which I just tried and instead of doing nothing it creates a duplicate window of the form1, I think things might work better if I create an instance of `CharStats` inside MainForm. I'm going to try converting that over and then I'll see how it works. (by adding a button to call C`CharStats` I mean

Comment: It's not throwing out errors or causing strange bugs now (with a button to call `CharStats` but it just doesn't do anything. I'll keep puzzling away at it.

Answer (score 0):

you problem seems a very good candidate for the observer pattern. see detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
.....

```
    public MainForm()
    {


        InitializeComponent();

//=====>Be careful change initial order between InitializeComponent

        CharStats form = new CharStats();
        form.Show();
    }

    public void SetInfo()
    {
        Variable2 = VariableLabel1;
        pcNameLabel.Text = Variable2;   
    }
}
```

And in the seconde form

```
public partial class CharStats : Form
    {
.....
 public void StatTransfer()
        {
            MainForm parentForm = this.parentForm;
            parentForm.formInit = 1;
            parentForm.SetInfo();
        }
......
}
```

Comment: I'll try that, one question though. Where did `parentForm` come from/ Where should I add it in?

Comment: It's a property of Form class http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx

Comment: So my debugger shouldn't be saying this `'charactertest.CharStats' does not contain a definition for 'parentForm' and no extension method 'parentForm' accepting a first argument of type 'charactertest.CharStats' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` when I try to use it?